# I encounter this Error: Multiple different uvs per loop at single vertex. when trying to export the model into mod3

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

So I'm trying to do some modding for MHW, I imported the mod3 of the Gae Bolg from chunk11 of the game, then imported the 3ds custom model.
After going through everything and making a UV map for it too, I try to export the model into mod3 file,
but I got this error instead:

> Meshes
>   600 instances of: ('rod008 001 LOD 1', 'Error: Multiple different uvs per loop at single vertex. Consider
>   marking islands as seams and then splitting at seams.')

I don't really understand what this is, can someone please help?

[image: **This is the model I'm working on**]

Answer (score 1):

Hello fellow MHW modder!

I hope you have latest add-on build, support for 2.8 isn't ready yet (as of post)
https://www.nexusmods.com/monsterhunterworld/mods/969?tab=files

You want to select your seams and break them from the model. 
For some reason the MT Framework engine (or add-on) doesn't like edge loops.
I'm still struggling with some of the other stuff.

Basically on your mesh, 
(first make sure you have triangulated faces, add-on will break and show an error)
Use the edge select, select your seam, press "V" to break (island) it off the mesh.

Here's more about this if you still need help: 
https://github.com/Ezekial711/MonsterHunterWorldModding/wiki/How-to-Fix-UVs-for-Objects-Sharing-Seams